# Can $10^n+89$ ever be a Perfect Square for $n>3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

Is it correct that if an natural number $10^n+89$ is a perfect square then $n=3$?

The answer is clear if $n$ is an even number. For odd $n$ I can prove that $10^n+89$ can be a perfect square only if $n=22m+3$...

Comment: Maybe we can show that the $+89$ can't change $10^{2n+1}$ enough to get it to be a square. Just an idea, I'm going to work this out and see if it works

Comment: Using Mordell's curve it is possible to prove that we can consider only numbers of the form $10^{6n+5}+89.$

Comment: @vrugtehagel That's just saying that $x^2-10y^2=89$ only has one solution with $y$ a power of $10.$ Not sure how one is going to prove that.

Comment: @Andrey: One can say that we have three Mordell's equations to consider : $y^3+89=x^2,y^3+8900=x^2$ and $y^3+890000=x^2$. (but, not sure how this is helpful...)

Comment: I think I got it, if the given form is perfect square then @vrugtehagel showed that $n=22m+3$ then one can show that 11 divides $10^n+89$ in this case! So 121 divides! Lets say $10^n+89 \equiv (-21)^m 10^3-32$ (mod 121) and since both are divisible assume $ = 121k$ that it is $121k$ now if $m >0$ then $(-21)^m 10^3 -32 \equiv k$ = $-2$ modulo 3. But that cannot happen since the number $10^n+89$ is divisible by 3!

Comment: @mathlove I belive that if the set of solution of the last equation is known, than this problem is solved.

Comment: @baharampuri, first of all, I take no credit for showing $n=22m+3$, I think the OP did that himself. Second, how did you derive $k\equiv-2\mod 3$ from $10^n+89=121k$?

Comment: $k=-1$ mod 3 actually sorry it is because $121k= (-21)^m 10^3 +89$ as $3 $ divides 21 we have $k=89$ mod 3.

Comment: $1089$ is the only **perfect power** of this form for $n\le10^3.$

Comment: $1089$ is also the only perfect square of this form for $n=22k+3,$ with $k\le10^4.$

Comment: @Lucian I belive that the the most clear way to solve this problem is to solve the equation $y^2=x^3+890000$. I have been told that there is quite effective algorithm for it, but I'm not good in programming.

Comment: @Andrey: I do know programming, but unfortunately I am utterly unfamiliar with number-theoretical algorithms. :-$)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a good point made by mathlove, the restriction of the base to a fixed number $(10)$ allows calculating three Mordell curves. The bad news is that neither Magma nor Sage is willing to do the final one. I will post the first two. Looking again, it appears the OP also was able to find solutions for the first two curves, but not the third. Looking through articles on computation written after 2005, say, it appears that most curves $y^2 = x^3 + k$ with $|k| \leq 100000$ have been done, but maybe not all, and in any case are not in any convenient websites. It would appear that $|k| > 100000$ makes it likely that nobody has finished the job.

Method: I had not written it down, it just looked correct. However, if
$$ y^2 = 10^{6k+3} + 89, $$ take $x = 10^{2k+1}$ to get
$$ y^2 = x^3 + 89. $$
 If
$$ u^2 = 10^{6k+1} + 89, $$
$$ 100u^2 = 10^{6k+3} + 8900, $$
 take $y = 10 u, \; \;x = 10^{2k+1}$ to get
$$ y^2 = x^3 + 8900. $$
 If
$$ v^2 = 10^{6k+5} + 89, $$
$$ 10000v^2 = 10^{6k+9} + 890000, $$
 take $y = 100 v, \; \;x = 10^{2k+3}$ to get
$$ y^2 = x^3 + 890000. $$

Meanwhile, note that there is an excellent selection of literature on Ramanujan-Nagell and Lebesgue-Nagell.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation  The bad news is that the vast majority of explicit solutions is for $x^2 + C = y^n$ where $C>0.$ For those, many relevant articles can be downloaded for free.

TWO OUT OF THREE MORDELL CURVES

```
============================================================

http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+

==================================================================

E_+00089: r = 2   t = 1   #III =  1
          E(Q) = <(-2, 9)> x <(-4, 5)>
          R =   1.2904854192
           8 integral points
            1. (-2, 9) = 1 * (-2, 9)
            2. (-2, -9) = -(-2, 9)
            3. (55, 408) = -1 * (-2, 9) + 1 * (-4, 5)
            4. (55, -408) = -(55, 408)
            5. (-4, 5) = 1 * (-4, 5)
            6. (-4, -5) = -(-4, 5)
            7. (10, 33) = -1 * (-2, 9) - 1 * (-4, 5)
            8. (10, -33) = -(10, 33)


=================================================================


E_+08900: r = 3   t = 1   #III =  1
          E(Q) = <(-20, 30)> x <(40, 270)> x <(20, 130)>
          R =   2.4097371874
           24 integral points
             1. (5, 95) = 1 * (-20, 30) - 1 * (40, 270)
             2. (5, -95) = -(5, 95)
             3. (-20, 30) = 1 * (-20, 30)
             4. (-20, -30) = -(-20, 30)
             5. (440, 9230) =  -2 * (-20, 30)
             6. (440, -9230) = -(440, 9230)
             7. (40, 270) = 1 * (40, 270)
             8. (40, -270) = -(40, 270)
             9. (-4, 94) =  -1 * (-20, 30) - 1 * (40, 270)
            10. (-4, -94) = -(-4, 94)
            11. (340, 6270) =  -1 * (40, 270) + 1 * (20, 130)
            12. (340, -6270) = -(340, 6270)
            13. (23245, 3544005) = 2 * (-20, 30) - 1 * (40, 270) + 1 * (20, 130)
            14. (23245, -3544005) = -(23245, 3544005)
            15. (16, 114) = 1 * (-20, 30) - 1 * (20, 130)
            16. (16, -114) = -(16, 114)
            17. (20, 130) = 1 * (20, 130)
            18. (20, -130) = -(20, 130)
            19. (200, 2830) = 1 * (-20, 30) - 1 * (40, 270) - 1 * (20, 130)
            20. (200, -2830) = -(200, 2830)
            21. (-11, 87) = 1 * (40, 270) + 1 * (20, 130)
            22. (-11, -87) = -(-11, 87)
            23. (3685, 223695) = 1 * (-20, 30) - 2 * (20, 130)
            24. (3685, -223695) = -(3685, 223695)
=======================================================================
```

Let me throw in

```
Magma
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 89 over Rational Field

    Torsion Subgroup is trivial
    Analytic rank = 2
    The 2-Selmer group has rank 2
    New point of infinite order (x = -4)
    New point of infinite order (x = -2)
    After 2-descent:
        2 <= Rank(E) <= 2
        Sha(E)[2] is trivial
    (Searched up to height 100 on the 2-coverings.)

[ (-4 : -5 : 1), (-2 : -9 : 1), (10 : 33 : 1), (55 : -408 : 1) ]

-------------------------------------------------------------------

Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 8900 over Rational Field

    Torsion Subgroup is trivial
    Analytic rank = 3
    The 2-Selmer group has rank 3
    New point of infinite order (x = 16)
    New point of infinite order (x = 40)
    New point of infinite order (x = -20)
    After 2-descent:
        3 <= Rank(E) <= 3
        Sha(E)[2] is trivial
    (Searched up to height 100 on the 2-coverings.)

[ (-20 : 30 : 1), (-11 : -87 : 1), (-4 : -94 : 1), (5 : -95 : 1), (16 : 114 :
1), (20 : -130 : 1), (40 : 270 : 1), (200 : 2830 : 1), (340 : -6270 : 1), (440 :
-9230 : 1), (3685 : 223695 : 1), (23245 : -3544005 : 1) ]

--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does all of this mean $?~($Were you able to find an example $?)$

Comment: @Lucian, these are all the integer solutions to $y^2 = x^3 + 89$ and $y^2 = x^3 + 8900.$ This does not finish the problem asked, however; since you ask, I did not find any other solution either.. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve

Answer (score 1):

This is a semi-proof that there are only finitely many solutions. I use the [abc-conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Formulations) here, which has so far not been confirmed to be proven (although Shinichi Mochizuki claimes to have a proof, hence my "semi-proof").

---

> **The abc-conjecture.**
>
> Given $a,b,c>0$ with $a+b=c$ and $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K_\epsilon$ such that
>   $$c<K_\epsilon\operatorname{rad}(abc)^{1+\epsilon}$$
>   where $\operatorname{rad}(x)$ denotes the product of the distinct prime factors of $x$.

So given that $10^n+89=s^2$, we know that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K_\epsilon$ such that

$$s^2<K_\epsilon\operatorname{rad}(10^n\cdot 89\cdot s^2)^{1+\epsilon}$$

note that $\operatorname{rad}(abc)=\operatorname{rad}(a)\operatorname{rad}(b)\operatorname{rad}(c)$ (for pairwise coprime $a,b,c$, and notice that $10^n$, $89$ and $s^2$ are pairwise coprime). So
\begin{align}
s^2&<K_\epsilon\operatorname{rad}(10^n\cdot 89\cdot s^2)\\
&=K_\epsilon\left(\operatorname{rad}(10^n)\operatorname{rad}(89)\operatorname{rad}(s^2)\right)^{1+\epsilon}\\
&=K_\epsilon\cdot\left(10\cdot 89\cdot \operatorname{rad}(s)\right)^{1+\epsilon}\\
&=K_\epsilon\cdot890^{1+\epsilon}\operatorname{rad}(s)^{1+\epsilon}\\
&\leq K_\epsilon\cdot890^{1+\epsilon}s^{1+\epsilon}
\end{align}
which means that

$$s^2<K_\epsilon\cdot890^{1+\epsilon}s^{1+\epsilon}$$

and dividing by $s^{1+\epsilon}>0$ gives

$$s^{1-\epsilon}<K_\epsilon\cdot890^{1+\epsilon}$$

for a fixed $\epsilon>0$, $K_\epsilon$ is fixed, and so is $890^{1+\epsilon}$, so there are at most finitely many solutions for $s$ (since $s$ is positive and bounded above by $\sqrt[1-\epsilon]{K_\epsilon890^{1+\epsilon}}$). Unfortunately, we don't know what $K_\epsilon$ is (except the lower bound $K_\epsilon>\frac{33}{890}29370^{-\epsilon}$ which we can find using the only solution we have), so unfortunately we still can't rule out those finitely many posibilities to get only $s=33$ (that's the solution $n=3$).

Comment: Actually it is not so difficult to prove that for every integer $k\ne 0$ Mordell curve $y^2 = x^3 + k$ has only finitely many integer points. And it is not wery difficult to reduce this problem to three Mordell's equations.

Comment: I haven't read much into Mordell curves yet, and since noone has said anything about the number of solutions, I figured I'd post this. But well, your comment appearantly shows that it has finitely many solutions without assuming the abc-conjecture - thanks for noting that :)